# docker compose overall stats

Tags: docker-compose, resources

docker stats gives resources usage "per container"

```
 $ docker stats --no-stream
CONTAINER ID   NAME                          CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
569311e0706a   foo                           2.92%     99.16MiB / 7.755GiB   1.25%     63.4kB / 35.3kB   0B / 0B     6
8dfc8de202c1   foo-db                        0.05%     208.1MiB / 7.755GiB   2.62%     36.4kB / 62kB     0B / 0B     29
6c58e58c667c   bar                           0.00%     384.5MiB / 7.755GiB   4.84%     1.57kB / 0B       0B / 0B     10
c62eabdc5343   baz                           0.00%     23.98MiB / 7.755GiB   0.30%     360kB / 4.12MB    0B / 0B     7
```

Is there a command to get resources usage (CPU, memory usage, net I/O, block I/O) for an overall docker compose stack? (on this example, the foo stack that includes foo and foo-db would gives (2.92+0.05=) 2.97% CPU, (99.16+208.1=) 307.26Mib mem usage, etc.)